# Xcode objective C classes importing

Tags: objective-c, class, xcode5

I have a project I'm working on that has a lot of repeated methods that I want to be able to access from both view controllers. I tried creating a class that contains all static methods and it works perfectly except I can only import it into one of the view controllers. Xcode says it's trying to compile the same code twice. Any idea of how to fix this? How can I import the same .m file to more than one view controller?

Comment: How are you importing your utility class (post the relevant section of code)? What is the exact error?

Comment: Are you using `#import` or `#include`?

Comment: The #include works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I can only import it into one of the view controllers. Xcode says it's trying to compile the same code twice.

It sounds like you are importing the implementation file (`.m`) instead of the header file (`.h`).

Your class should have its interface defined in the header file and its implementation in the implementation file.  You import the header file.

Answer (score 0):

if its anything like c++ you can use pre-processor directives as follows:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

//your class code here

#endif
```

Objective c also has an #import directive that checks to make sure files are only included once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding the file to your project once and importing the custom class `.h` file into each `viewcontroller`

Answer (score 0):

Import the `.h` file in the *-Prefix.pch file in your project. You'll find:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "YourClass.h"
#endif
```